# How to test try result in orElseTry function call

Tags: dataweave

How can I test the result of a dw::Runtime::try() function call in a following orElseTry function call? I want to match the result kind (the error type), and take different actions based on the type of error thrown by the previous try, but no have to match if the try() result status is true or false.

I'm trying to emulate the typical try/catch Java style where I catch various types of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? You will basically need to store the result of the `try()` to evaluate later

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::Runtime
var d =  "" /* change to number to work */
---
do {
    var opp = try(() -> 1 + d)
    ---
    if(opp.success) 
        opp.result
    else if(opp.error.kind == "UnexpectedFunctionCallTypesException")
        "expected error"
    else
        "unexpected error"
}
```

Comment: I already know how to test the result of a try() function with a match operator, but that does not use orElseTry() and orElse(). The orElseTry() is nice because it's only called if the try() result's "success" value is false, so it saves a step in the testing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what result you are after but you can continuously do try's using orElseTry() as you mentioned. Sample code below will do the following: it will try if num is a string / number, add 1, if failed try appending "1" if it is an array else just write value of num to consider other cases.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::Runtime
var num =  {}

---
{
    result: try(() -> num + 1) orElseTry (num ++ 1) orElseTry (num)
}
```

So changing the value of num from above code will result to following:

if num = 1

```
{
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "result": 2
  }
}
```

if num = []

```
{
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "result": [
      1
    ]
  }
}
```

if num = {}

```
{
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "result": {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is with pattern matcher but with types

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

type Error<Kind <: String> = {success:false, error: {kind:Kind}}

import * from dw::Runtime
--- 
try(() -> fail("first try") )
    orElseTry fail("second try")
    // orElseTry "Three times the charm!"  //uncomment to see log message
match {
    //if(ue.error.kind == "UserException") 
    case ue is Error<"UserException"> -> 
                ue orElse 
                        fail("ERROR: getUsers failed with a UserException error: " ++ write(ue, "application/json"))
    else ->  
        log(
            "INFO: One of the try or orElseTry functions succeeded.", 
            $ orElse fail("Unhandled Error: " ++ write($.error, "application/json")) 
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this type of pattern to test the type of error caught by a try/orElseTry function, then conditionally fail or log a message with the previous caught error information. This pattern logs the message if any previous try/orElseTry function succeeds. Otherwise one of the fail functions throws an error that includes the previous thrown error information, and the error if filtered by the "kind" of error.

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    
    import * from dw::Runtime
    
    try( () -> fail("first try") )
orElseTry fail("second try")
//orElseTry "Three times the charm!"  //uncomment to see log message
match {
    case ue if(ue.error.kind == "UserException") -> 
        ue orElse fail("ERROR: getUsers failed with a UserException error: " ++ write(ue.error, "application/json"))
    case result if(true) ->  log(
        "INFO: One of the try or orElseTry functions succeeded.", 
        result orElse fail("Unhandled Error: " ++ write(result.error, "application/json")) 
        )
}
```